# Slider not fill when ray is cast

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working on `unity3d` and facing a problem. In scene there is a `Main Camera`, which has a child object as `worldspace canvas`, and that canvas also has a child object which is a image.[image: Main Camera] I attached the script `MouseLook` for rotating the camera, camera cast a ray by pressing `A` key. Also in the scene there is a `WorldSpace canvas` which has a `box collider` component and a child object `Slider`, and canvas attached with the script `SliderSelect`.[image: Slider]

That script taking a reference of slider `gameobject` and has a `Coroutine` which fills the slider when we cast a ray through the camera to the canvas by pressing `A` key. My code is working fine but it doesn't fill the slider correctly. It's change the scene immediately when ray is cast. What i want is first slider is fill and audio is play than slider value equal to 0.Than scene change. I think i'm doing something wrong in `Coroutine`.

Code:
RayCast Script:

```
public class RayCast : MonoBehaviour
{
    private RaycastHit hit;

    [SerializeField]
    private AudioSource source;

    [SerializeField]
    private AudioClip clip;

    //Refrence of Slider Canvas Script
    [SerializeField]
    private SliderSelect sliderCanvasScript;

    private void Update()
    {
        Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, transform.forward, Color.cyan);

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A) && SliderSelect.check)
        {
            if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.forward, out hit, 9f))
            {
                if (hit.collider.gameObject.name == "SliderCanvas")
                {
                    Debug.Log("Ray cast to the slider");
                    StartCoroutine(sliderCanvasScript.FillUp());
                    source.PlayOneShot(clip);
                    SceneManager.LoadScene("Scene0", LoadSceneMode.Single);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Slider Select Script:

```
public class SliderSelect : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private Slider mSlider;

    public static bool check;
    private void Start()
    {
        mSlider.minValue = 0;
        mSlider.maxValue = 100;
        mSlider.wholeNumbers = true;
        mSlider.value = 0;
        check = true;
    }

    public IEnumerator FillUp()
    {
        int i = 0;

        while (i <= 100)
        {
            mSlider.value += 2;
            i += 2;
            yield return null;
        }
        mSlider.value = 0 ;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My code is working fine but it doesn't fill the slider correctly. It's
>   change the scene immediately when ray is cast. What i want is first
>   slider is fill and audio is play than slider value equal to 0.Than
>   scene change. I think i'm doing something wrong in Coroutine

That's because you are calling

```
StartCoroutine(sliderCanvasScript.FillUp());
source.PlayOneShot(clip);
SceneManager.LoadScene("Scene0", LoadSceneMode.Single);
```

in from the `Update` function which really doesn't wait for the `FillUp()` coroutine function to finish.

Start a new coroutine function from the Update function then execute those three lines of code in that coroutine function. You can then replace `StartCoroutine(sliderCanvasScript.FillUp());` with `yield return StartCoroutine(sliderCanvasScript.FillUp());` which will wait for it to finish before calling `source.PlayOneShot(clip);` followed by `SceneManager.LoadScene("Scene0", LoadSceneMode.Single);`.

Also, to wait for audio to finish playing, don't use the static `PlayOneShot` function.

First, assign the clip to the AudioSource with `source.clip = clip;`. Now play with `source.Play();`. Next, wait for Audio to finish playing with `while (source.isPlaying){ yield return null;}`. That's it.

This is what that function should look like:

```
IEnumerator doInOrder()
{
    //Wait for Fill to finish
    yield return StartCoroutine(sliderCanvasScript.FillUp());
    //Assign Audio Clip
    source.clip = clip;
    //Then Play Sound
    source.Play();

    //Wait for Audio to finish Playing
    while (source.isPlaying)
    {
        yield return null;
    }
    //Load new Scene
    SceneManager.LoadScene("Scene0", LoadSceneMode.Single);
}
```

This is what the whole code should look like:

```
public class RayCast : MonoBehaviour
{
    private RaycastHit hit;

    [SerializeField]
    private AudioSource source;

    [SerializeField]
    private AudioClip clip;

    //Refrence of Slider Canvas Script
    [SerializeField]
    private SliderSelect sliderCanvasScript;



    private void Update()
    {
        Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, transform.forward, Color.cyan);
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A) && SliderSelect.check)
        {
            if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.forward, out hit, 9f))
            {
                if (hit.collider.gameObject.name == "SliderCanvas")
                {
                    Debug.Log("Ray cast to the slider");
                    StartCoroutine(doInOrder());
                }
            }
        }
    }

    IEnumerator doInOrder()
    {
        //Wait for Fill to finish
        yield return StartCoroutine(sliderCanvasScript.FillUp());
        //Then Play Sound
        source.clip = clip;
        //Then Play Sound
        source.Play();

        //Wait for Audio to finish Playing
        while (source.isPlaying)
        {
            yield return null;
        }
        //Load new Scene
        SceneManager.LoadScene("Scene0", LoadSceneMode.Single);
    }
}
```

**Don't put a Collider on a Canvas UI component**

`Colliders` should only be used on Sprites/SpriteRenderer(2D Objects) and MeshRenderer(2D Objects). It should never be put on a Canvas UI component.

Even though this is working for you, you should detect click on a slider with `OnPointerClick` then detect slider value change with the `onValueChanged` event. The script to detect these two things must be attached to the `Slider` GameObject. You can then implement 2 events that you can register to and receive callbacks when there is a click or `Slider` value change on the `Slider`.

Attach the script below to your slider:

```
public class SliderDetector : MonoBehaviour, IPointerClickHandler
{
    public Slider slider;

    public delegate void sliderClicked();
    public static event sliderClicked OnClicked;

    public delegate void valueChanged(float value);
    public static event valueChanged onValueChanged;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Awake()
    {
        slider = GetComponent<Slider>();
        //Subscribe To Slider Event
        slider.onValueChanged.AddListener(delegate { sliderCallBack(slider.value); });
    }


    public void OnPointerClick(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        if (OnClicked != null)
        {
            //Notify All Subscribed function
            OnClicked();
        }
    }

    void sliderCallBack(float value)
    {
        if (onValueChanged != null)
        {
            //Notify All Subscribed function
            onValueChanged(value);
        }
    }

    void OnDisable()
    {
        //Un-Subscribe To Slider Event
        slider.onValueChanged.RemoveListener(delegate { sliderCallBack(slider.value); });
    }
}
```

Then to use it from your `Raycast` script add the following to it:

```
void OnEnable()
{
    //Subscribe to the Slider Click event
    SliderDetector.OnClicked += OnSliderClicked;
    //Subscribe to the Slider Value Changed event
    SliderDetector.onValueChanged += OnSliderValueChanged;
}

//Will be called when there is a click on that slider
private void OnSliderClicked()
{
    //Slider Clicked Start your coroutine function
    StartCoroutine(doInOrder());
}

//Will be called when the slider value changes
private void OnSliderValueChanged(float value)
{
    //Slider Value Changed, Do Something
}

void OnDisable()
{
    //Un-Subscribe to the Slider Click event
    SliderDetector.OnClicked -= OnSliderClicked;
    //Un-Subscribe to the Slider Value Changed event
    SliderDetector.onValueChanged -= OnSliderValueChanged;
}
```

Comment: slider is fill correctly, but audio is not play because scene is loaded!

Comment: Check the update. It's modified to fix the audio problem too.

Comment: Thanks for your detail answer. One more thing i want to ask if we use `[SerializeField]` for taking reference only for one scene, can we disable that  `[SerializeField]` in next scene. Because next scene doesn't have reference for this field. How can we do that?

Comment: I don't think you understand what `SerializeField` is used for. It is only used to make a private variable show up in the Editor. If you want GameObject to remain for the next scene, you have to use the  `DontDestroyOnLoad` function and also the Singleton patter.  You can google `DontDestroyOnLoad`  and Singleton for more information.

Comment: I just realized you have a collider on a UI element should never do this. Check my updated answer for that.

Comment: I'm making this for virtal reality, that's why i put collider on it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129382/discussion-between-hamel123-and-programmer).

Comment: why my sound is playing multiple times.

Comment: I think you should create new post with your current code that is playing twice. There you can explain where the script is attached to and what is colliding with.